# How to get "GuestCartId" for Magento 2 rest api?

Tags: magento2, api

I'm trying to get the correct id of the cart but when I use " /rest/default/V1/guest-carts/" it generates something like "x2xfmemslsmw" but when I access the cart and come what is being used is different. How can I get the User's GuestCartId value?

Answer (score 1):

Guest cart quote ids (cart ids) are masked for security reasons. So it returns encoded quote id. That is correct way. You should use that masked quote id. Since it is guest cart, you should send that masked quote id in other requests, and magento will decode it and will use it.

For example look here how guest cart items are managed vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestCartItemRepository.php . You will see there is masked_id, when loading quote. That is how magento load guest cart, using that masked quote id, that you get in response.

Comment: And how can I get GuestCartId from guest? To use in my module

Comment: Try this
```use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory;
/** @var $quoteIdMask \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMask */
$quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id');
$quoteId = $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId();```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current cart Id using this code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;
}

public function MyCustomFunction(){
    return $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
}
```